# Sequential subtraction within a vector - in R, without using LOOP

Tags: r, subtraction, sequential

Consider a list with length of n

```
a <- list(c(5, 41, 75, 158, 269, 432, 630, 901, 1534))
```

I am trying to make a sequential subtraction within this list. My goal is performing sequential subtraction by 1, making each elements 1 less than previous element, as the list is elongated.

As a result, I wish to have numbers in list as following:

```
a <- list(c(5, 41-1, 75-2, 158-3, 269-4, 432-5, 630-6, 901-7, 1534-8))
```

My 'pseudo-code' is as follows (which I cannot do in real-life R)

```
a[[1]][n] <- (a[[1]][n]-(n-1))
```

But again this does not work in real R.

Any recommendation in doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As it is a `list` of 1 vector, extract the `vector` with `[[` and subtract from the sequence of 'a' (subtracted from 1)

```
a[[1]] <- a[[1]] - (seq_along(a[[1]]) - 1)   
a
#[[1]]
# [1]    5   40   73  155  265  427  624  894 1526
```

---

If it is a `list` with more than one `vector` use `lapply`

```
lapply(a, function(x) x - (seq_along(x) - 1))
```

Or with `relist`

```
relist(unlist(a) - (sequence(lengths(a))-1), skeleton = a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(a,function(x,y)x-y,y=seq(from=0,length.out = length(a)))
```